# Access Internet From My Blackberry App

Tags: blackberry

This is my first attemp to code a blackberry app so please bear with me.

I am developing an app to make it easy to access certain information from certain websites using screenscrapping.

Now I am done with the ui part of the application onto the internet access part.

My question is how do i access internet from my app ? I see that blackberry offers http, wifi and some other forms to access the internet ... does my app need to be worried about what mode is being used ? or as far as my app is concerned theres a general api to access the net with the logic of connecting to the internet being handled by the device itself ..?

any pointers with some sample code would be much appreciated.

thank you,
ankit

Answer (score 2):

Blackberry applications internet access is a nightmare.

Good starting point here: http://www.versatilemonkey.com/blog/index.php/2009/06/24/networking-helper-class/

Helped me.